# Checkstyle right curly brace position -- when set 'alone' gives message 'Must be on same line'

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have tried Googling this but have been unable to find the solution.  I am running Eclipse for Java Luna.  Using the Sun Eclipse styles, I modified the Left Curly Brace Position to be 'nl', and the Right Curly Brace Position to be 'alone'. It all works fine except when a right brace is followed by 'else', or 'catch' (maybe others such as 'finally'... I have not checked).  In this case, I have a code section that looks like

```
    ... 
}
catch ( whatever )
{
    ...
}
```

The brace prior to the catch gives an error that says *'}' should be on the same line*.  If I move the right brace to the end of the preceding line, I get:

```
Multiple markers at this line
'}' should have line break before.
'}' should be on the same line.
'}' should be on a new line.
'if rcurly' have incorrect indentation level XXX, expected level
```

If I move the 'catch' to the same line as the '}', I get:

```
'}' should be alone on a line.
```

I am new to CheckStyle and I assume I have left some other required option set incorrectly.  What documentation I have found has given me no indication of how to fix this.  I searched the checkstyle tag on StackOverflow but did not find a similar problem.  Any help or pointer to where I can get help will be appreciated.

The config file reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<!--

    This configuration file was written by the eclipse-cs plugin configuration editor

-->
<!--

    Checkstyle-Configuration: Sun Eclipse With Personal Checks

    Description: 

Based on the Sun Eclipse but with values that I prefer

-->
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="LeftCurly">
      <property name="option" value="nl"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly"/>
    <module name="Indentation"/>
    <module name="RightCurly">
      <property name="option" value="alone"/>
    </module>
  </module>
</module>
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration file?

Comment: You have duplicate entries for the `RightCurly` module - one empty and one with the "alone" option set. Perhaps the empty one is being used and the other dropped, resulting in the default option being set?

Answer (score 1):

recheck that you use latest checkstyle and try to reproduce that base on CLI - http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html

```
$ cat checkstyle_checks.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">

  <module name="TreeWalker">

    <module name="LeftCurly">
      <property name="option" value="nl"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_CATCH"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_ELSE"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_FINALLY"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_IF"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY"/>
    </module>

    <module name="RightCurly">
      <property name="option" value="alone"/>
    </module>

    </module>
</module>

    $ cat PropertyCacheFile.java 
final class PropertyCacheFile
{
    PropertyCacheFile()
    {
        if (true) 
        {
            //code
        }
        else 
        {
            //code
        }
            try 
            {
             // NCODE
            }
            catch (final IOException e) 
            {
                // SMTH
            }
            finally 
            {
                /// VALUES
            }
    }
}

$ java -jar checkstyle-6.5-all.jar -c checkstyle_checks.xml PropertyCacheFile.java 
Starting audit...
Audit done.
```

Comment: Good thought but no joy.  The file is the latest (6.5).  Using the command line, I get the same results: PetriParser.java:771:9: warning: '}' should be on the same line.

Comment: Please make a post at https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/checkstyle and please provide logs of your launch and all files